# how to recognize which key is pressed custom keypad and which text field is selected

Tags: iphone

i need to add custom keypad in app.

for that i add the [images on buttons](http://b.imagehost.org/download/0994/keypad) like this.

i have 10 textfields in my app.

when ever i press the keys i need to print on selected textfield.

How can  i recognize which button is clicked,which textfield is selected.

can any one pls post some code.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the tag property of each textfield to a different value. Pass in the textfield as the sender argument to the IBAction. Check the tag of the argument.

Comment: Because of the pointer nature of Objective-C, you can then pass a pointer to the proper property(/textfield) that the user tapped in, and pass that as an argument to various methods which you might use to populate the textfield with text. That's one of the good things about pointers...